# How to fix Django "NoReverseMatch" Error

Tags: python, django

I have built a simple blog app with Django and I have had some issue with NoReverseMatch.

Here are my problem screenshots:

1. https://prnt.sc/imqx70
2. https://prnt.sc/imqwpt

Here is my code on Github: https://github.com/nafiulhasanbd/Django_blog_app

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Please post errors themselves and not screenshots, also post the relevant parts of the code. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also post the traceback so you can see where the error is actually happening

Comment: good question, couldn't find the error. posting this message to be posted when answer arrives.

Comment: @sarthakupadhyay I am not sure where is the error my all codes hosted on github I have already provided the link

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py line 77 change

```
return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```

to

```
return redirect(PostDetailView, pk=post.pk)
```